# Angular 8 location.reload is giving infinite loop on component, how to avoid?

Tags: angular

I am developing an application that uses a javascript library called pogo-slider which is called in the index.html of the angular application, but when I use the routing system, routerLink for example, the pogo slider is not reloaded, it is only reloaded when I I give F5 Refresh on the page. Even leaving the onSameUrl option on the route, I can't get the desired effect.

I tried to solve with location.reload in the component, but it is giving an infinite loop.

I tried to leave onSameUrlNavigation enabled in the module, but did not reload the javascript files.

```
homepage.component.ts

ngOnInit() {
this.refresh()
}

refresh() {
location.reload();
}
```

I need to go to the desired route and reload the javascript files present in index.html, similar to the effect of F5 (location.reload)

updating:
This is a pogo slider code in **functions.js** on **assets/js/functions.js**

```
//===============================================================================
  function initPogo() {
    $('#heroSlider').pogoSlider({
      autoplay: true,
      autoplayTimeout: 6000,
      displayProgess: true,
      preserveTargetSize: false,
      targetWidth: 1000,
      targetHeight: 300,
      responsive: true,
      pauseOnHover: false
    }).data('plugin_pogoSlider');
  }
```

and the index.html

```
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.pogo-slider.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/functions.js"></script>
```

Comment: Off course it will go into an infinite loop as you are calling the method in ngOnInit which gets called every time the page is loaded. A Stackblitz example will help to identify the issue

Comment: Please post the code of how you're using pogo-slider, because it sounds like you're not using Angular properly (especially when considering that pogo-slider is a jQuery plugin)

Comment: @Ansuman, Yes, I need to reload once after the component is created, but I can not find a way, I will try to put in the stackBlitz here and provide the link

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to reload. You could use ngOnInit life cycle hook to initialise anything you want. Can you paste your component code.

Comment: @nullptr.t Updated post with code

Comment: @Ansuman Unfortunately, the project forced me to use old javascript, jquery libraries, which are in index, so reloading would be the only way to make it work when switching routes.

Comment: You need to bring your code into your .ts file so you can call initPogo() after your desired lifecycle event. Or you can make a separate component just for your plugin.

Comment: @nullptr.t A separate component just for my plugin pogo ? I'll try here, then give you feedback

Answer (score 0):

initPogo() should be triggered from ngAfterViewInit() life cycle hook and this should load slider.
Remove reload from ngOnInit